# Tips and Debugging of a function that creates or loads options

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I wrote a function inside a class, in which an options file is created or, if it already exists, the options are loaded. Now, the function works and not having problems, so my question more than anything else is if there are errors that I don't see (which maybe in the long run can create problems), if and how it is possible to write it better (advice) and if there are other controls that I can add in case an external user tampered with the file.

The function is this:

```
def load_opt(self):
    from TcEngine import default_options

    self.target_fps = default_options.target_fps

    video_opt = os.path.exists("TcEngine/video_opt.py")
    if not video_opt:
        with open("TcEngine/video_opt.py", 'a+') as f:
            self.screen_size = default_options.screen
            f.write("screen = " + str(self.screen_size) + "\n")
            self.fullscreen = default_options.fullscreen
            f.write("fullscreen = " + str(self.fullscreen) + "\n")
            self.fps = default_options.fps
            f.write("fps = " + str(self.fps) + "\n")
    else:
        from TcEngine import video_opt

        opt_dmg = []
        opt_error = []
        if hasattr(video_opt, "screen"):
            if type(video_opt.screen) is tuple:
                if len(video_opt.screen) == 2:
                    check = 0
                    for item in video_opt.screen:
                        if type(item) is int:
                            check += 1
                    if check == 2:
                        self.screen_size = video_opt.screen
                    else:
                        self.screen_size = default_options.screen
                        opt_error.append("screen")
                else:
                    self.screen_size = default_options.screen
                    opt_error.append("screen")
            else:
                self.screen_size = default_options.screen
                opt_error.append("screen")
        else:
            self.screen_size = default_options.screen
            opt_dmg.append("screen")
        if hasattr(video_opt, "fullscreen"):
            if type(video_opt.fullscreen) is bool:
                self.fullscreen = video_opt.fullscreen
            else:
                self.fullscreen = default_options.fullscreen
                opt_error.append("fullscreen")
        else:
            self.fullscreen = default_options.fullscreen
            opt_dmg.append("fullscreen")
        if hasattr(video_opt, "fps"):
            if type(video_opt.fps) is int:
                if video_opt.fps >= 24 and video_opt.fps <= 120:
                    self.fps = video_opt.fps
                else:
                    self.fps = default_options.fps
                    opt_error.append("fps")
            else:
                self.fps = default_options.fps
                opt_error.append("fps")
        else:
            self.fps = default_options.fps
            opt_dmg.append("fps")

        if len(opt_dmg) > 0:
            os.remove("TcEngine/video_opt.py")
            with open("TcEngine/video_opt.py", 'a+') as f:
                f.write("screen = " + str(self.screen_size) + "\n")
                f.write("fullscreen = " + str(self.fullscreen) + "\n")
                f.write("fps = " + str(self.fps) + "\n")
            opt_dmg = []

        if len(opt_error) > 0:
            new_opt = ""
            with open("TcEngine/video_opt.py", 'r') as r:
                for line in r:
                    new_opt += line
                new_opt = new_opt.split("\n")
                for error in opt_error:
                    if error in self.__dict__:
                        new = error + " = " + str(self.__dict__[error])
                        for numb in range(len(new_opt)):
                            if error in new_opt[numb]:
                                new_opt[numb] = new
            os.remove("TcEngine/video_opt.py")
            with open("TcEngine/video_opt.py", 'a+') as f:
                for value in new_opt:
                    f.write(value + "\n")

            opt_error = []
```

The `default_options` module looks like this:

```
screen = 1024, 576
fullscreen = False
fps = 60
target_fps = 60
```

How should I proceed? Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: use `try/except` to catch errors and `logging` to write information in file - so later you can check if there was problem.

Comment: Mhh, thanks, I'll add this too.